# Terraform, Ignore specific app setting azurerm

Tags: terraform, azure-rm

I'm using Terraform and right now I'm in a situation where all my appsettings for my apps is being populated as the infrastructure might change. This way it's all automatic.

However, I've got a problem with my linux consumption plan Functions app that has an appsetting that needs to be set during deployment. WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE is the value that is set to a URL during deployment.

My problem is that terraform will remove this value or set it to whatever I set it to.

How can I get this value to stay as is during terraform deployment?

Either getting the value from azure or ignoring the value in terraform?

I found this but it does not seem to work for the appsettings section.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#ignore_changes

My test:

```
resource "azurerm_function_app" "shipping-broker-msw-func" {
  name                       = "shipping-broker-msw-func"
  ...

  app_settings = {
    ...
    "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE"        = "URL_Form_CD"
  }

   lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      app_settings["WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE"],
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I got the same issue. Please, post here if you find a solution. In my case I configure a docker container into the web app, and that's for my set-up not a infrastructure settings but Terraform tracks it as any other app setting. So when I change the container it pops like there is a change in infrastructure but I do not want terraform to track that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Terraform documentation: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#ignore_changes

[image]

So it seems the reason is that, when you first create the app service, you need to include the key (with a dummy value possibly) in order to be able to specify later on that you wanna ignore it.

If you did not include the key at the very beginning, you can still add it later on. So just add in your configuration that key with a dummy value, and then the `ignore_changes` seems to work. In my case it worked.

Comment: This is the answer   Here's some background of why it happens (zip deployment, run from package, linux consumption): https://www.maxivanov.io/ignore-azure-functions-application-settings-change-in-terraform/

Comment: Documentation link is stale, new one is: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html#ignore_changes